# How to install microbiomeSeq package?

Tags: r, installation, package

I've been having a lot of trouble installing the package "microbiomeSeq" in Rstudio.
I keep getting errors like:

```
ERROR: dependency 'KMDA' is not available for package 'microbiomeSeq'

removing 'C:/Users/14142/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/microbiomeSeq'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/Public/Documents/Wondershare/CreatorTemp/Rtmpc7iXOi/file7643cdd730b/microbiomeSeq_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
library(microbiomeSeq)
Error in library(microbiomeSeq) :
there is no package called ‘microbiomeSeq’
```

Comment: Okay, so `KMDA` is not installed yet. What happens when you try `install.packages("KMDA")`?

Comment: This is the error I got: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/14142/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘KMDA’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: Is there another way to install the package?

Comment: I see. The package was removed from CRAN because of unresolved/unanswered problems. You can bypass this if you need by doing `remotes::install_github("cran/KMDA")` (if you don't have `remotes` installed, it _is_ available, so `install.packages("remotes")` will work).

Comment: Thank you, that worked! ( I want to mark this as resolved, but I am not seeing an option)

Answer (score 0):

The `KMDA` package has been archived from CRAN:

> *Archived on 2022-06-14 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders.*

Perhaps the maintainers will resolve this and republish (perhaps unlikely since the package has not been updated since 2015), but until then you can install it from github. Note: all (I think) CRAN packages are mirrored in their basic form under https://github.com/cran. I say "basic" because it is not a clone of the original github repo (if it is even on github), it is just a repo that is generated from the source tarball of packages released on CRAN.

```r
if (!"remotes" %in% installed.packages()[,1]) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("cran/KMDA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the package from the archives:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/KMDA/KMDA_1.0.tar.gz
```

Then, assuming you are in the same directory as the downloaded package, install this manually:

```
R CMD INSTALL KMDA_1.0.tar.gz
```

After this you may try to install the microbiomeSeq again and this dependency won't create any conflict. The above solution assumes you are using a Linux based OS. You may also install it from your R session in any OS as follows:

```
install.packages('pathto/KMDA_1.0.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')
```